# Headings of matrix in color

Tags: matrices

Is there a simple way to create this matrix using LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: I'd like to thank all of my colleagues for some wonderful answers. This will help my students a great deal.

Answer (score 5):

Must it be called a matrix? Or is tabular OK?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c l}
   & & \color{blue}From: & & & \\
   & \color{blue}D & \color{blue}R & \color{blue}L & & \color{blue}To: \\
   \ldelim[{3}{*}[P = ] & .70 & .10 & .30 &\rdelim]{3}{*} & \color{blue}D \\
   & .20 & .80 & .30 & & \color{blue}R \\
   & .10 & .10 & .40 & & \color{blue}L \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: bigdelim does not show up on my Tex Live Utility.

Comment: Install the multirow package.

Comment: van Ooostrum The multirow package is installed on our school's Miktex systems, but bigdelim does not show up on the miktex package manager.

Comment: `bigdelim.sty` is distributed as part of the `multirow` package. The package contains `multirow.sty`, `bigstruts.sty` and `bigdelim.sty`.

Comment: OK, multirow is installed on the school windows computer (Miktex 2.9):  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\multirow\bigdelim.sty"). But trying to compile your code, we get this error: ! Undefined control sequence.
\@ldelim #1#2#3[#4]->\multirow 
                               {#2}{#3}{\ensuremath {\left .\vcenter {\hsize...
l.11    \ldelim[{3}{*}[P = ]
                             & .70 & .10 & .30 &\rdelim]{3}{*} & \color{blue...

Comment: OK, I see. Add the line `\usepackage{multirow}' to your document. The new version of `bigdelim` does that automatically, but I had forgotten that with an old version you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigdelim}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c >{\color{blue}}l}
                     & & \color{blue}From: \\
                     & \color{blue}D      & \color{blue}R & \color{blue}L & & To: \\
\ldelim[{3}{*}[P = ] & .70 & .10 & .30 &\rdelim]{3}{*} & D \\
                     & .20 & .80 & .30 & & R \\
                     & .10 & .10 & .40 & & L \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need yesterday's [2016-11-30] `tabstackengine` version V2.01 to accomplish it this simply.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}[2016-11-30]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
\fixTABwidth{T}
\savestack\thematrix{$\bracketMatrixstack{~~.70~~ & .10 & .30\\.20&.80&.30\\.10&.10&.40}$}
P = \color{cyan}\stackon{\thematrix}{
  \stackon[5pt]{\makebox[\maxTABwd]{D}\makebox[\maxTABwd]{R}\makebox[\maxTABwd]{L}}{From:}
} ~~\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}\stackon{\Centerstack[c]{D\\R\\L}}{To:}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}[2016-11-30]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\savestack\thematrix{$\bracketMatrixstack{.70 & .10 & .30\\.20&.80&.30\\.10&.10&.40}$}
P = \color{cyan}\stackon[6pt]{\thematrix}{
  \stackon[5pt]{%
    \makebox[\TABwd{1}]{D}\kern2ex\makebox[\TABwd{2}]{R}\kern2ex\makebox[\TABwd{3}]{L}}{From:}
} ~~\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}\stackon[6pt]{\Centerstack[c]{D\\R\\L}}{To:}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also had to install listofitems

Comment: @David Yes, a number of my packages, including `tabstackengine`, rely on the `listofitems` package to parse data.  `listofitems` is a great package in its own right.

Comment: B. Segletes I'm at school now and listofitems does not show up on the Miktex Package Manager (I'm a mac user at home). How do I get it installed on our miktex systems at school?

Comment: @David You should be able to update the package database on MikTeX.  However, barring that, http://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems is where it can be had.  You need `listofitems.tex` and `listofitems.sty`, as well as the English or French documentation PDF.

Comment: @David The `listofitems.tex` file goes in your repository in the`tex\generic\listofitems` subdirectory, while `listofitmes.sty` goes in the `tex\latex\listofitems` subdirectory.  Documentation goes in the `doc\generic\listofitems` subdirectory.  Elsewise, you can leave it all in your current working directory, until you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray,xcolor}
\newcommand{\chead}[1]{\mbox{\small\color{cyan}#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{blockarray}{ r @{} *{3}{c} >{\color{cyan}}c }
         &     & \chead{\makebox[0pt]{From:}} \\
         & \chead{$D$} & \chead{$R$} & \chead{$L$} & \chead{\makebox[0pt]{To:}} \\
    \begin{block}{ r @{} [ *{3}{c} ] >{\color{cyan}}c }
         & .70 & .10 & .30 & D \\
    P =~ & .20 & .80 & .30 & R \\
         & .10 & .10 & .40 & L \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```